# how can i make jquery modal dialog and bootstrap same

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/x76UH/4/

I have two modals ob which comes with default bootsrap and other the jquery UI.

Is there any way to make the jqueryUI modal dialog same as bootrsap one so that it also comes from top with same overlay

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "close" );
        }, 1500 );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my suggestion dont merge the two UI's with each other, make is happen with one only, as you said you want bootstrap like modal in JqueryUI...

Here's a demo i created... http://jsfiddle.net/945Tt/4/

Do not forget to add the background overlay to this html:-

```
<div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
```

For changing the color of the dialog box, edit it by [Jquery UI Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), a tool for modifing the Jquery UI, you can also select themes from the Gallery in that page...

Hope this work for you...

Thanks...

Comment: thankas . Is there any way to bring the daglof near top of screen . not in middle. Just like modal. and also chnage the color of buttons